# VBA on Webpage throws automation, unspecified error at HTML document

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, internet-explorer-9, excel-2010

I'm doing automation for a webpage.  I just need to do a simple task (set a value on the page) but I cannot get it to work.  Here's a cut from my code.

```
Dim IExp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim hCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim hInp As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim hPoint As MSHTML.tagPOINT

Set IExp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IExp.Visible = True
IExp.navigate "http://somesite.com/"

Do Until IExp.Busy = False
    DoEvents
Loop

Set hDoc = IExp.document

' Find the "search for" input box on the page
Set hCol = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each hInp In hCol
```

The code throws an exception at this line

```
Set HTMLdoc = iExp.Document
```

Error says:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Automation error
Unspecified error
```

I just want it to throw a single string on the webpage.

Things that might help:

```
 - Just need to run the htmldoc line without error
 - By the way, im using IE9 and MS Excel 2010.  I added vb.net tag as I know I could edit some syntax to get it to work with vba.
 - I tried changing my references and the declared variables.  I used MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, and also the code with CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") but they also don't work.
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think the problem might be with what you have referenced, and the fact that you don't specify what library you are referencing HTMLDocument from:

Try changing

```
  Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
```

To:

```
  Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```

If that sorts it out, make sure you don't have multiple libraries referenced that have a HTMLDocument object.

I just tested the code in Office 2013 referencing 'Microsoft Internet Controls' and 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' only and it worked fine for me.

Sure I have had a similar problem in the past when I had different XML libraries reference both using an xDocument object.